# Standard length of male header pins

Tags: connector, breadboard, header

I'm [shopping](http://www.digikey.ca/product-search/en?pv90=1&pv69=80&pv589=25&FV=fff40016%2Cfff802f3%2C70078c%2C1640001&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) for some bulk male header pins and noticed a ***lot*** of options for the contact length column. I know 1" is a longer pin than I'm used to and 0.1" is too short, but is there a standard length for these parts, or a fairly standard range of lengths?

I guess for many applications, it's not gonna matter, but when I'm buying a lot of them, they'd better be the right length!

EDIT: breadboards are the main target for these headers.

Comment: What will the pins be mating with?

Comment: Breadboards, and standard female headers, mostly. (female headers don't seem to specify a contact length)

Comment: The great thing about standards is there are so many to choose from!

Comment: @tummychow you'd be surprised about the variations in female header variation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

""Standard"" length means any length that fits your desired use, unless you are talking about using them with some specific goal in mind.

A through hole header has five main dimensions. Pitch between pins, size of the pin, length of the bottom side, length of the post, and length of the top side.

[image]

The most common are 0.1" pitch, 0.025" square pins. "A" in that picture is the side that goes through your pcb. If your pcb is very thick, and A is too short, you will not be able to properly solder it. If the pcb is too thin and A is too long, you could short something out, have a lopsided board or have to cut them. "C" in that picture is the top side length. This mates with a connector. Too short and it might not be secure or might not have a good electrical connection. Too long, and the connector doesn't sit flush with the posts, so you might end up bending them.

**Having just measured a ide/pata header, it is ~0.25" C with a B total length of ~0.435" (7/14th) (eyeballed/rounded). For samtec parts, this is actually A = 0.100", C = 0.230", B = 0.430". This is the general IDE/PATA standard header, and pretty much all computer headers fit this.**

Personally I find those too small for breadboard or general use, longer headers are more useful (I go with slightly longer .126/.456/.230 or headers that are pretty much end up equal length on both sides of a pcb .300/.630/.230)

Comment: Yeah, I'm mostly looking for breadboard-compatible headers. I'm guessing the order of those dimensions is A/B/C? It seems the digikey "contact length" column is referring to C but I'll check the drawings to be sure. And by "too small for general use", you were referring to A=0.1"?

Comment: @tummychow yes. The 0.1" bottom length is a bit too short for a breadboard, makes it too easy to pop out. C is normally contact length, as c is the one that mates with another connector.

Answer (score 0):

The ones I'm holding in my hand are about 6mm. That should work for anything but the most recessed sockets.